# Software for multiple text presets (Windows)

Tags: windows, macros

I need a software that I can pop up with a hotkey and have visual pre-set text sections to choose from. Upon click, text should be inserted wherever my focus was (Skype, web chats etc). I need it to hold unlimited text presets and either let me name them or let me glimpse them so I know which is which. It would be ideal if I could divide them into subsections as well.

Comment: how about text expansion? Like in iOS (eg. typing `omw` = `on my way` automatically

Comment: It would have to be text macros to work like //omw = on my way, still, I need way to many presets to remember all // commands, that's the only problem. But I'll take what I can get, if there isn't something that's identical to what I'm after

Comment: Does http://www.phraseexpress.com/ look like it will work for you? Look at the gif in the link and you can see it's features. I think it does what you want :)

Comment: That looks exactly right! I'll test this, but if you were to move you comment to an answer, I'll mark it proper!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want looks like it can be solved with Text Expansion. If you don't know what this is, it's basically like in iOS, where you can set it up to replace certain words with phrases (eg. `omw` = `on my way`).

[PhraseExpress Text Expander](http://www.phraseexpress.com/index.html) is a perfect text expander for Android and Windows.

Features:

- free (for personal use)
- portable
- integration with Outlook
- easy to use
- can set up hotkeys
- can choose which programs to work in (whitelist)
- includes auto correct words by default to correct commonly misspelled words (it just did so for `misspelled`)
- can choose text from popup:

[image]
(type in 'trigger' and press space to see them, Note: `quotes` is built-in)

GIF from their website:

[image]

[image]